# Optimize QuerySets in a Loop with indexes and better SQL

Tags: python, django

I have a View that returns some statistics about email lists growth. The models involved are:

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email_list = models.ForeignKey(EmailList, related_name='contacts')
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', related_name='contacts')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class EmailList(models.Model):
    customers = models.ManyToManyField('Customer',
        related_name='lists',
        through='Contact')


class Customer(models.Model):
    is_unsubscribed = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    unsubscribe_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

In the View what I'm doing is iterating over all EmailLists objects and getting some metrics: the following way:

**view.py**

```
class ListHealthView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        start_date, end_date = get_dates_from_querystring(request)

        data = []
        for email_list in EmailList.objects.all():
            # historic data up to start_date
            past_contacts = email_list.contacts.filter(
                status='active',
                create_date__lt=start_date).count()
            past_unsubscribes = email_list.customers.filter(
                is_unsubscribed=True,
                unsubscribe_date__lt=start_date,
                contacts__status='active').count()
            past_deleted = email_list.contacts.filter(
                status='deleted',
                modify_date__lt=start_date).count()
            # data for the given timeframe
            new_contacts = email_list.contacts.filter(
                status='active',
                create_date__range=(start_date, end_date)).count()
            new_unsubscribes = email_list.customers.filter(
                is_unsubscribed=True,
                unsubscribe_date__range=(start_date, end_date),
                contacts__status='active').count()
            new_deleted = email_list.contacts.filter(
                status='deleted',
                modify_date__range=(start_date, end_date)).count()

            data.append({
                'new_contacts': new_contacts,
                'new_unsubscribes': new_unsubscribes,
                'new_deleted': new_deleted,
                'past_contacts': past_contacts,
                'past_unsubscribes': past_unsubscribes,
                'past_deleted': past_deleted,
            })
        return Response({'data': data})
```

Now this works fine, but as My DB started growing, the response time from this view is above 1s and occasionally will cause long running queries in the Database. I think the most obvious improvement would be to index `EmailList.customers` but I think maybe it needs to be a compound index ? Also, is there a better way of doing this ? Maybe using aggregates ?

**EDIT**

After @bdoubleu answer I tried the following:

```
data = (
    EmailList.objects.annotate(
        past_contacts=Count(Subquery(
            Contact.objects.values('id').filter(
                email_list=F('pk'),
                status='active',
                create_date__lt=start_date)
        )),
        past_deleted=Count(Subquery(
            Contact.objects.values('id').filter(
                email_list=F('pk'),
                status='deleted',
                modify_date__lt=start_date)
        )),
    )
    .values(
        'past_contacts', 'past_deleted',
    )
)
```

I had to change to use `F` instead of `OuterRef` because I realized that my model `EmailList` has `id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True, salt='...')` was causing `ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` but I'm not completely sure about it.

Now the query works but sadly all counts are returned as 0

Comment: I'm not Django expert, it seems to be that you're doing multiple queries in the loop body: `email_list.contacts.filter`, `email_list.customers.filter` but I'm not sure

Comment: FYI `Subquery` won't work with `F`, it has to be `OuterRef`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is your code is producing 6 queries for every `EmailList` instance. For 100 instances that's minimum 600 queries which slows things down.

You can optimize by using [`SubQuery()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) expressions and `.values()`.

```
from django.db.models import Count, OuterRef, Subquery

data = (
    EmailList.objects
    .annotate(
        past_contacts=Count(Subquery(
            Contact.objects.filter(
                email_list=OuterRef('pk'),
                status='active',
                create_date__lt=start_date
            ).values('id')
        )),
        past_unsubscribes=...,
        past_deleted=...,
        new_contacts=...,
        new_unsubscribes=...,
        new_deleted=...,
    )
    .values(
        'past_contacts', 'past_unsubscribes',
        'past_deleted', 'new_contacts',
        'new_unsubscribes', 'new_deleted',
    )
)
```

**Update**: for older versions of Django your subquery may need to look like below

```
customers = (
    Customer.objects
    .annotate(
        template_count=Subquery(
            CustomerTemplate.objects
            .filter(customer=OuterRef('pk'))
            .values('customer')
            .annotate(count=Count('*')).values('count')
        )
    ).values('name', 'template_count')
)
```

Comment: This is awesome, but: `ProgrammingError: subquery must return only one column` and if I add something like: `Contact.objects.values('id').filter(...)` I get: `ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Comment: *"Very, very definitely"* the right answer [concept ...] here.  If possible, use an SQL monitor to let you see what the Django-generated queries actually are.  Then, use subqueries or whatever-else-you-have-to so that *the SQL server* is doing the work using as few queries as possible.  What's killing you right now is that you're turning-around the communications link 600 times.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza my mistake - I forgot to add `.values('id')` to the end of the subequery (it has to be after the filter). Should be good to go now.

Comment: @bdoubleu I would imagine `values('id')` to return 1 row but: `ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` ?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza is it possible you missed the `Count()`? If not could you please paste your code

Comment: @bdoubleu I appreciate your help, I think my problem now lies on the primary key of the `EmailList` model as I edited my question.